# Why doesn't JavaScript work in Chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

The main idea is to put a website inside the extension, this website has scripts, but they are not running. All of the links are relative, even the options page scripts are not working.

```
<script>
   alert("a");
</script>
```

Am I missing something in the `manifest.json` file?

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "Extension",
    "description": "This is an extension.",
    "version": "1.0",
    "background": {
        "scripts": ["background.js"]
    },
    "permissions": ["tabs" , "contextMenus"],
    "browser_action": {
        "default_icon": "icon.png"
    },
    "content_scripts": [
        {
            "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
            "js": ["./website/scripts/JvScripts.js"]
        }
    ],
    "options_page": "options.html"
}
```

Comment: See [csp](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy.html).

Comment: Are there any error messages from the dev tools?

Comment: Can it be that you have the `<script>` tag within your javascript file?

Answer (score 1):

Your script should run fine. I have just set up a similar one on [github](https://github.com/k0pernikus/stackoverflowQuestion17772418).

On the `option_page` you have to link to the script you want to run in the html, it does not get injected. This is due to security.

In your `options.html` you will have to add:

`<script src="relative/path/to/your/options.js"></script>`

Do not forget to reload your extension every time you make a change to your script.

For simple changes you might find [extension reloader](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/extensions-reloader/fimgfedafeadlieiabdeeaodndnlbhid) useful, only bear in mind that you have to reload manually from the extension setting page when your `manifest.json` changes.

Comment: i'm really really really sure that i linked the scripts correctly, i told you that i just wrote a script for "alert" and it didn't worked .... as for "js": ["website/scripts/JvScripts.js"] i've  tried also and it didn't work ..

Comment: @AmbiguousTk See my example github extension on https://github.com/k0pernikus/stackoverflowQuestion17772418

Answer (score 0):

Endeavor to remove the script tag from your javascript file. I do believe that would help